# Akka Typed: MDC on ChildFailed

Tags: java, akka, akka-typed

We are using the MDC by setting it up via

```
Behaviors.withMdc(
 SomeMessageType.class,
 msg -> toMap( msg.getSomeIdentifier() ),
 originalBehavior );
```

This is, in itself, not a problem and works as expected. Unfortunately, it creates a problem with Supervision: We watch our child actors, let them die and the parent will take action then. This also works, only with one problem:

The MDC information is lost, when the parent gets the `ChildFailed` signal. This is no surprise, since it's potentially another thread, definitely another message/signal, thus MDC was cleared. But for the parent logging, it would be nice to have access to the child's MDC when it crashed.

Is this possible out of the box or will we have to somehow implement it ourselves, for example by caching that information?

Comment: Not out of the box, but note that Lightbend Telemetry (aka Cinnamon), a commercial addon, can propagate the MDC alongside message sends.

Comment: Even if I were to consider that, I don't need to be able to see MDC in another app, I need it during runtime in the application itself for our logging. Sending data to another app to then somehow consolidate it with our logging would be a huge waste of time.

Comment: Who said anything about another app?

Comment: That said, Akka Typed is generally of the opinion that a parent shouldn't have that level of visibility into the internal workings of its children.  This is made clear from comparing typed supervision to classic supervision: the former gets a simple `ChildFailed` signal, the latter gets the exception that caused the failure.  An MDC is arguably even more detail than that.

Comment: While I don't disagree, that means that context simply gets lost on supervision, which one could argue is bad, since how can you supervise correctly with an incomplete set of information?